# Why does N! stop overflowing the 32 bits output variable when N>=34?

Tags: c, factorial

Is there any limitation of variable overflow for big numbers? There is an exercise in a C book about factorials.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int n, fn, counter;
    //puts("enter nonnegative int");
    //scanf("%u", &n);
    n = 1;
    while (n != 34) {
        fn = n;
        counter = n - 1;
        while (counter > 0) {
            fn *= counter;
            counter--;
        }
        printf("%u\n", fn);
        n++;
    }
}
```

The commented lines are for debugging.

This code prints the factorial of numbers from n(1) to 34 (`'while(n!=34)'`), but if you increase it to something like 36 it will just print 0 after first 34 outputs. I know most of the outputs are overflowed and am controlling these big numbers very poorly.

However, I would like to know what limits are causing these zeros to occur.

Comment: Hint: `34!` is a multiple of `2^32`...

Comment: You can only contain 12! in a 32-bit `int`, all the higher ones have overflowed. BTW you can compute factorials in a loop from the previous result: you don't have to start over with every one.

Comment: Just do a search for something like [c max int value](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+max+int+value&rlz=1C1EJFC_enAU871AU871&oq=c+max+int+value&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i457j0i433j0l2j69i60l3.2194j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah i know. my question is why it stops overflowing after output of 34. btw thanks, i will improve my algorhitm

Comment: The answer to your question is in the very first comment you received, @NateEldredge's hint.

Comment: To be clear: the more 2's (or values with powers of 2 as factor) you multiply by, the more 0's come in at the bottom, because multipying by 2 is the same as shifting left. An overflowed `int` doesn't stay overflowed and keep getting larger: all there is, is whatever relic is left in the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You complain that

> `N!` stops overflowing the 32 bits output variable when `N>=34`

meaning that, after `34!`, the result keeps remaining to 0.

Well, the answer is that **it doesn't stop overflowing**. What happens is that the value shown, that is the remainder of the division `N! / 2^32`, starting from N=34 becomes 0 and will never change.

In order to understand how it can happen, let's start with an example using a decimal number. We'll display the result of N! using a display with only two digits:

| Factorial | Actual result | Displayed result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1! | 1 | 01 |  |
| 2! | 2 | 02 |  |
| 3! | 6 | 06 |  |
| 4! | 24 | 24 |  |
| 5! | 120 | 20 | Overflow! |
| 6! | 720 | 20 | Overflow! |
| 7! | 5040 | 40 | Overflow! |
| 8! | 40320 | 20 | Overflow! |
| 9! | 362880 | 80 | Overflow! |
| 10! | 3628800 | 00 | Overflow and the shown value is **00**! |
| 11! | 39916800 | 00 | Overflow and the shown value is still **00**! |
| 12! | 479001600 | 00 | Overflow and the shown value is still **00**! |
| .. | .. | 00 | **The shown value will be 00 forever** |

As you can see, the display overflows at `5!` where we can also notice how the result is a multiple of `5*2=10`. For obvious reasons all the subsequent results will be a multiple of `5*2=10` so they will have a trailing 0.
But when we reach `10!` a special condition occurs: **the result becomes a multiple of `(5^2)*(2^2)=10^2=100`** so, whatever is the multiplication we perform afterwards, the shown value will always be `00`.

Remember this info: **we reached the *all-0 condition* when the result started having the common factor of B^N**, where

- `B` is the base of the representation (10)
- `N` is the number of shown digits (2)

So, in this case,  `10^2`.

---

The same reasoning can be done using a binary (base-2) representation, limited by the size of a `unsigned int`. We will reach the all-0 condition when the result will start having the common factor of `B^N = 2^32`.

And when will the result become a multiple of `2^32`? Let's count the multiplications introducing powers of 2:

- `2!` will add a factor 2 (2^1 in total)
- `4!` will add a factor 2^2 (2^3 in total)
- `6!` will add a factor 2 (2^4 in total)
- `8!` will add a factor 2^3 (2^7 in total)
- `10!` will add a factor 2 (2^8 in total)
- `12!` will add a factor 2^2 (2^10 in total)
- `14!` will add a factor 2 (2^11 in total)
- `16!` will add a factor 2^4 (2^15 in total)
- `18!` will add a factor 2 (2^16 in total)
- `20!` will add a factor 2^2 (2^18 in total)
- `22!` will add a factor 2 (2^19 in total)
- `24!` will add a factor 2^3 (2^22 in total)
- `26!` will add a factor 2 (2^23 in total)
- `28!` will add a factor 2^2 (2^25 in total)
- `30!` will add a factor 2 (2^26 in total)
- `32!` will add a factor 2^5 (2^31 in total)
- `34!` will add a factor 2 (**2^32 in total)**

From now on the factorial will always be a multiple of `2^32`, so the shown result, the remainder of `N! / 2^32` will always be 0.

Answer (score 4):

There are no limitations and the overflow never stops.
It's just that when `n` arrives at 34, `fn` overflows to the number 0.

Then the next number will be 35 * 0, the next 36 * 35 * 0, and so on.

Nothing mysterious.

Comment: it that just your guess or you have any proof? i changed n to 40 and its still zero.

Comment: It's not a guess, the proof is your code. Every output of the program is a multiple of the precedent output. So as soon as one of them overflows to 0, your program will print only 0s (cause 0 is the only possible multiple of 0)

Answer (score 1):

Maximum value for a variable of type `unsigned int`, `UINT_MAX = 4294967295`.
In the process, after finding `12!` its get `overflowed`. To handle the overflow C wraps around the value which is also called `modulo wrapping`.
For example,

```
unsigned int x = 4294967295;
x += 1;
printf("%u", x)
```

output: `0`

```
unsigned int x = 4294967295;
x += 2;
printf("%u", x)
```

output: `1`

that means whenever overflow occur, `C` wrap around the value and it's never get overflowed!

But in this case, while finding the 35! somewhere in the process the modulo become zero. Therefor,after `34!` it's always `zero`.
so, the zero is not appearing for overflow.

To find the required bit for `n!` use the formula, `floor(log(n!))+1`.
then use the required data type.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, as pointed out by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil), the maximum unsigned int value can perhaps most easily be displayed by

```
printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
```

***** edit above - origiinal answer below *****

`fn` is of type `unsigned int` that will have a maximum value.

To find out the maximum value of an `unsigned int` try

```
printf("%d",sizeof(unsigned int));
```

This command will tell you the number of bytes in memory allocated to an `unsigned int` - if that number is `n` then the largest `unsigned int` value will be
2^{8n}-1 - or two to the power of 8n  then subtract 1.

If you want to have a larger number then you could test other types like `long`.

If you are happy to get approximate values then you could use the type `double`, which will go much higher than any `int` type.

Comment: i know unsigned int is tiny for this program. i could use long as you said.  but my question is why after output of 34 next ones dont get overflow again. why it stops overflowing

Comment: It's at least 20 years we have "long long int" or int64_t

Comment: To see the maximum value of `unsigned int`, use `printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);`, after including `<limits.h>`. While the method you describe works in typical C implementations, the C standard allows bytes to have more than eight bits (so the largest value might be greater than 2^(8n)−1) and allows `unsigned` to have padding bits (so the largest value might be less than 2^(8n)-1).

Comment: `printf("%d",sizeof(unsigned int));` -> `printf("%zu", sizeof(unsigned int));`

Comment: @ulix yes, I didn't want to go through all the different options, just point in the direction of the long variable types

Comment: @EricPostpischil - ok you got me here - I was not aware of bytes with more than 8 bits! --- and the uint_max is another thing I learnt - thanks for the useful comment

Comment: @chqrlie - ok so the zu is also new to me, thanks for the helpful comment

Comment: `%zu` is the C99 format for values of type `size_t` such as `sizeof(unsigned int)`. Since this value cannot exceed the range of `int`, you could also write `printf("%d", (int)sizeof(unsigned int));`