# How can I modify this code to print out the rest of the factorial numbers. It stops at 33

Tags: c

**This here is my C program code**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_FACTORIALS 10000
#define NUM_FACTS 100

struct FactorialResults
{
  int results[MAX_FACTORIALS];
  int numResults;
};

int factorial(const int n)
{
  return (n > 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

void computeFactorials(struct FactorialResults *results, int numFactorials)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < numFactorials; i++)
  {
    results->results[i] = factorial(i);
  }
  results->numResults = numFactorials;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct FactorialResults results = {{0}, 0};
  int i;
  computeFactorials(&results, NUM_FACTS);
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_FACTS; i++) 
  {
    printf("%5d %12d\n", i, results.results[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**My output**

[my program output here it goes all the way up to 99 but i just took a sample to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pi9U.png)

I tried modifying to void function to loop through all the numbers but somehow it doesn't. So I'm stuck here

Comment: Don't the negative results prior to 33 give you cause for alarm, and possibly point to a deficiency in your thinking?

Comment: @Kes, please edit and post your output as _text_.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Aside from the issues mentioned in other comments, `results->results[i] = factorial(i);` is easily replaced with `results->results[i] = i * results->results[i - 1];` - i.e., there's no need to recompute the entire value.

Comment: Try: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: At some points the result exceeds the size of the type used to store it (in your case 32 bits integer). Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65647449/11336762)

Comment: FYI 99! is `933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 2):

To exactly print all the factorials from 0! (1) to 99! (9.332...*10<sup>155</sup>) requires 519 bit integer math.

OP's `int` is 32-bit and overflow readily occurs after 12!

Even `uintmax_t`, the widest defined available type is only certainly 64-bit.

Code must be able to do multiplication using wider math.  There are many solutions such as using an array 156 of `unsigned char`, each representing a decimal digit or ready-made *bignum* libraries.  Another is to use [`string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47514950/2410359) math.  There are *many* others.  The choice is yours.